# Is there an equivalent to "Don't keep activities" in iOS?

Tags: ios, android-activity

On my Android test device I can go to `Settings->Developer Options` and set `Don't keep activities` an option to destroy activities as soon as the user leaves them.

[image: Destroy Activities]

Is there an equivalent feature for iOS developers that concern ViewControllers?

`EDIT`

I know that `Activity` is not a concept in iOS. That is why my question concerns `ViewControllers` which would be the closest concept.

When you press the home button on an iOS device the app disappears from screen. But its view controller is still running on the background. If you double click the home button you can see all apps that can be resumed. Is there an option for users or developers to avoid that, so when one presses the home button the app would be closed instead of running on background?

Comment: What do you mean by "destory". Do you mean deallocate (remove from memory/RAM?). I'm not super familiar with Android Activities. I do know somewhat about them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Activity" is not a concept that exists in iOS. Like all objects in iOS, the objects live as long as there is something that is retaining them. Once all retainers are released, objects are deallocated, thus destroyed.

This holds for view controllers. If you present a view controller stack and dismiss it, if you do not hold these controllers, they will be released. If you do not see the controllers released, you may have an incorrect design (such as strong properties instead of weak) or a memory leak, which can be caused due to multitude of reasons, a common one being retain cycles.

To kill your app when it enters background, add the `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` key to your plist, with the value of `Yes`.

---

A creative way to give such an option to your customers/testers is to provide such a toggle in your Settings.bundle, and if it is set to `YES`, call `exit(0);` when the application goes to background (such as in `applicationDidEnterBackground:`). Not sure what your exact use case is, but for debugging, this can work.

Comment: So I guess the answer is "No, there isn't"?

Comment: @GabrielOshiro See my edit following your edit. You should have asked just that.

Comment: That is not an answer to my question because it is not something that can be set on the iOS nor on Xcode for debug purposes. That would be hard coded on the app itself. But thanks a lot @Leo Natan

Comment: @GabrielOshiro See my last edit for a creative way to create such a toggle.

Comment: Yeap, that is exactly what I was thinking about doing ;-) Thanks again